# Solving congruence system by deducting equations with one another

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences

I need to get the general solution for the next congruence system 
$$3x+4y \equiv 2 \bmod 13\\
2x+6y \equiv 1 \bmod 13$$
I have thought of multiplying one of the equations by some number and then deducting it from the other equation so one of the variables disappears but I can't think of the right way to solve the entire system.

Comment: I see no problem with that idea.  Where exactly are you getting stuck?

Comment: The problem is that I should multiply one of the equations by a non-integer number, which I am not sure is correct.

Comment: You must multiply by inverses modumo $13$. Don't forget $\mathbf Z/13\mathbf Z$ is a field since $13$ is prime.

Comment: There should be no need to multiply by a non-integer number.  You could multiply the first equation by 2 and the second by 3 and subtract or, probably easier, multiply the second equation by 5 and add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
3x+4y &\equiv 2 \bmod 13 \tag{1}\\
2x+6y &\equiv 1 \bmod 13 \tag{2}\\
10x+30y &\equiv 5 \bmod 13 \tag{3 [5$\times$(2)]}\\
10x+4y &\equiv 5 \bmod 13 \tag{4}\\
13x+8y &\equiv 7 \bmod 13 \tag{5 [(1)+(4)]}\\
8y &\equiv 7 \bmod 13 \\
y &\equiv 9 \bmod 13 \tag{6}\\ \hline
2x+54 &\equiv 1 \bmod 13 \tag{7 [(6)$\to$(2)]}\\
2x+2 &\equiv 1 \bmod 13 \\
2x &\equiv 12 \bmod 13 \\
x &\equiv 6 \bmod 13 \\ \hline
&\bigstar
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$2(3x+4y)-3(2x+6y)\equiv2(2)-3(1)\pmod{13}$$

$$\iff-10y\equiv1\pmod{13}\iff3y\equiv1\iff y\equiv-4\equiv9$$
as $3(-4)\equiv1\pmod{13}\iff3^{-1}\equiv4$

$$3x+4y\equiv2\implies3x+4(9)\equiv2\iff3x\equiv-34\equiv5\iff x\equiv5(-4)\equiv-20\equiv6$$